# Cannot remove iTunes (installed with WINE) from Unity Applications lens

Tags: 11.04, unity, wine

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I remove un-installed programs from the Unity dash menu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75214/how-can-i-remove-un-installed-programs-from-the-unity-dash-menu)

I installed iTunes 10 via PlayOnLinux and later uninstalled it. However, the app icon still shows up in Unity's Applications lens and I cant find where to delete it at all.

I tried looking in `usr/local/application` and in `usr/share/application` etc. etc. I've also searched the whole computer: Apple Software Update, About iTunes, Quicktime, etc. etc., but iTunes still shows up in my Applications lens and is clickable. When I click it, the lens closes as if to launch iTunes but since it's been uninstalled, nothing happens.

Please help, this is annoying as hell and I just switched from Win 7 to Natty. I don't need WINE but want my app lens back to normal.

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at the `~/.local/share/applications/wine` folder (and subfolders). You'd need to delete the *.desktop* files belonging to the applications in question.

Comment: I had this same problem with some wine apps i had installed, and this was where the .desktop files were hiding.