# How can I remove un-installed programs from the Unity dash menu?

Tags: 11.10, unity, unity-dash

The **Unity dash** seems to operate independently from the **Gnome main menu**. This is quite annoying. I've uninstalled many (Wine) apps, removed their entries from the Gnome main menu, but they appear in the Unity dash. Also, KDE apps that I've removed from the Gnome menu still appear in the Unity dash. How can I remove these entries?

**Edit:** This question also applies to other un-installed apps.

Answer (score 17):

These applications leave Desktop Files somewhere in `~/.local/share/applications`. Search through this folder (and any sub folders) for the relevant launchers, and if you find any, delete them :).

Then simply run `unity` from the run dialogue (<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f2</kbd>) to restart Unity.

Comment: This also works with OpenOffice. I didn't need to restart unity.

Comment: I just tested this answer and it works. If you have panel opacity set to zero (as I have), you may find that the panel is no longer transparent. So, log out and log in and things are put right.

Comment: +1 Fixed my problem :)  Had been looking this info for days

Answer (score 1):

None of it worked for me.
What I did

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to open terminal,

```
sudo su #to log as super user
```

enter your su password,

```
cd .local/share/applications,  
ls -l
```

See if you see `.desktop` in here.
If you do, then issue  `rm -f -r .desktop` to delete the file.