# Remove app shortcuts from Unity?

Tags: 11.10, unity, wine, unity-dash, uninstall

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I remove un-installed Wine programs from the Unity dash menu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75214/how-can-i-remove-un-installed-wine-programs-from-the-unity-dash-menu)

Sorry if this has already been asked. I installed a couple of apps with Wine, which I un- and then re-installed, but they still appear in the Unity dash. How can I remove them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `alacarte` to edit the menus or delete the relevant .desktop files from `~/.local/share/applications`.

Comment: Thanks, but which .desktop files are which? Will alacarte give them the proper names? Which ones do I need?

Comment: the .desktop files that are named according to the applications you removed in wine.

Comment: Alacarte didn't work, but I deleted the relevant files from ~/.local/share/applications. I also removed the files from the wine folder in ~/.local/share/applications, was that right?

Comment: @dragon it wasn't necessary, but it's okay.